# Finding and deleting dates in column vba

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am trying to create a function that will scan through a column and delete (or replace with nothing) any date of any form. 8/24 or 8/24/16. I have been unable to find an efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Try the [IsDate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9(v=vs.90).aspx) function.

Comment: Which way are you trying to do that?

Comment: So far I use random dates and use the replace function to find and replace dates... I am trying to go through a string that is in a single cell, and delete any date that is there, preserving the rest of the text. For example: "The car is almost ready EDD -  08/24/16 and performs well" to show "The car is almost ready and performs well"

Answer (score 0):

Check below code. Guess this will do

```
    Sub Change_Dtfld2Blank()
    cllRange = 100 ''SpecifyNo of rows in question
    clNum = 1 '''Specify Colum Number
    sSheetname = "Sheet2" ''Specify Sheet name
    
    For i = 1 To cllRange
        If IsDate(Sheets(sSheetname).Cells(i, clNum).Value) Then
            Sheets(sSheetname).Cells(i, clNum) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```